# Prevent model set `change` event when clearing model and resetting to defaults?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am setting a model on submission of a contact form so I'm grabbing all of the input values, creating an object literal then setting this on the model. I have a `change` event listener that then outputs a summary screen. I also have a reset button that clears the model and resets the model to the defaults. My problem is that this reset also triggers the change event which then displays the summary screen, which I don't want. Is it possible to prevent this?

**Examples of my Backbone View**

```
initialize: function() {
        console.log('ContactForm::initialize');

        this.listenTo(this.model, 'invalid', this.onModelInvalid);
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.onModelSet);
    },
onFormSubmit: function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        var inputs = this.el.querySelectorAll('.js-input');

        this.setModelData(inputs);
    },

    setModelData: function(elements) {

        var attributes = {};

        for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {

            var thisInput = elements[i],
                thisInputValue = thisInput.value;

            attributes[thisInput.id] = thisInputValue;
        }

        this.model.set(attributes, { validate: true });
    },

    /*
     *  this.model returned, this model will contain an array of validation errors accessed via this.model.validationError
     *  loop through these and output each error field.
     */
    onModelInvalid: function() {
        console.log('ContactForm::onModelInvalid', this.model.validationError);

        this.toggleValidationClass('add');
    },

    onModelSet: function() {
        console.log('ContactForm::onModelSet', this.model.toJSON());

        Backbone.Events.trigger('show:summary', this.model);
    },

    onFormReset: function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        // Reset the model to default
        this.model.clear().set(this.model.defaults);

        // Reset form fields
        this.$('.js-form')[0].reset();

        // Remove all invalid classes if errors exist
        if(this.model.validationError && this.model.validationError.length > 0) {
            this.toggleValidationClass('remove');
        }

        console.log(this.model.toJSON());
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an (undocumented by [.set](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set)) option called `silent`

(For some reason, the docs for [.clear](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-clear) mentions it though).

Relevant source on github: https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L482

So try

```
this.model.clear({silent:true}).set(this.model.defaults, {silent:true});
```

[Demonstration on plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZcRkX4VfjiZbUlDY1UoD?p=preview) using the following code

```
var model = new Backbone.Model();

model.on('change', function(e) {
  document.write(JSON.stringify(e.changed));
});

model.set('foo', 'bar'); 
model.clear({silent: true}).set('foo', 'bar', {silent: true});
model.set('test', '123');
```

Running this writes `{"foo":"bar"}{"test":"123"}` to the document, so the line where `{silent:true}` was passed to `.clear()` and `.set()` did not generate any change-events.

Comment: `{silent:true}` still seems to trigger the event

Comment: @styler It's working [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZcRkX4VfjiZbUlDY1UoD?p=preview) (only two events are generated and those are from where `silent` was not set)

Comment: @styler If you can make a plnkr (or jsfiddle) of it not working I can probably take a look as well. There might be events triggered from somewhere else in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use an attribute on the model to tell if it's newly loaded or being reset. Set it to `true` in `onFormReset` and test for it in `onModelSet`.

Comment: Yeah I had thought if this as I don't think `{silent:true}` works for me

Comment: Can I pass in an option to the model.clear().set? Like: `this.model.clear().set(this.model.defaults, {
            reset: true
        });`

Comment: Either send it to the `clear`, or just use the `set`. Why would you need both?